# Python: Load data into a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm curious about loading data from a file into a dictionary of dictionaries.

1st dictionary: key=x, value=2nd dictionary

Just for conceptualization, if it was:
dictionary(key, value) it would be..

```
dictionary(x, dictionary(y, rating))
```

y and rating are elements in the nested dictionary.

I'm specifically interested in how that would look syntax wise and what would it be like if then a function like *get_rating(x)* was called.

Comment: Depends what you file looks like. With the right file, it's a single call to `pickle.load` or `json.loads`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interactive Python prompt:

```
>>> a = { 1: { 'a': 'v1', 'b': 'v2' }, 2: { 'a': 'v3', 'b': 'v4'}}
>>> a[1]['a']
'v1'
>>> a[2]['a']
'v3'
>>>
```